# Strange results when searching if value exists in list

Tags: python

Here's the area of code I'm having problems with. T1 and T3 are both lists of lists:

```
for num in T1:
    print num
    print T3[0]
    print type(num)
    print type(T3[0])
    if num == T3[0]:
        print 'they are the same!'
    else:
        print 'nope they are not!'
    if T3.index(num):
            print 'number exists in list!'
```

Here's the result:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0]
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
they are the same!
```

The values and types are the same but when I don't see 'number exists in list!'   When I tested `list_name.index(value)` on the command line it works but not here.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `list.index()` returns the *index* of its argument in the list, and raises a `ValueError` if the argument isn't found.  The check

```
if T3.index(num):
```

basically tests if the index of the argument is non-zero, but it happens to be zero in your example, so the check fails.  You probably want to test if the item is contained in the list -- use

```
if num in T3:
```

to that end.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly.  Just to mention, I tried to simplify for the example but the T3.index(num) statement was actually wrapped in a try statement.  I know Try's are not good for flow control and your way actually shows me a way I don't need to use it.  Thank you, you taught me two things(for the price of one).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
if T3.index(num):
            print 'number exists in list!'
```

the `index()` method of lists does this: "Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item."

In your list, the first value to look for (0) is at index 0. The if statement treats the zero value as False, and correctly does nothing.